# Why real functions with positive derivative map open intervals to open intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I am considering a smooth function $f: I \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and $f'(x)>0$ everywhere. How do I show that $f$ maps any open interval in $I$ to an open interval?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $f$ is a bijection since $f'(x)>0$. Now by the inverse function theorem we have that $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable, and thus continuous. We may conclude that $f$ is a homeromorphism. Hence it maps open intervals to open intervals.